# Is this the correct implementation for insertion sort in ruby

Tags: ruby, sorting, insertion-sort

I'm trying to do array practice problems and I'm working on insertion sort right now. I'm wondering whether this code is clear and readable. To me it looks kind of confusing, if anyone has a cleaner way(easier to understand) to implement this can you help me please?

```
def insertion_sort(arr)
(1...arr.length).each do |i| #iterate through array go through every element
    j=i-1 #to check all elements behind i
    while(j>=0&&arr[i]<arr[j]) #while not out bounds and current element is less than previous
        temp=arr[i] #3 lines to switch arr[i] and arr[j]
        arr[i]=arr[j]
        arr[j]=temp
        i=j #keep track of where i is 
        j-=1 #decrease j by 1 to check the previous element
    end
end
return arr
end
```

Comment: What immediately comes to mind is that your indenting is terrible, and hence not easily readable. On stackoverflow, the common indenting rule for Ruby is to insert two spaces. Also it is bad because you did not put spaces around binary relations/equal signs.

Comment: This question belongs on [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/?as=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably has its own issues, but you can see a couple simplifications here to *hopefully* make the code more readable.

```
class Array
  def swap(a, b)
    self[a], self[b] = self[b], self[a]
  end
end


def insertion_sort(arr)
    (1...arr.size).each do |i|
        i.downto(1).each do |j|
            break if arr[j] >= arr[j - 1]
            arr.swap(j, j - 1)
        end
    end
    arr
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't necessary in ruby:

```
temp=arr[i] #3 lines to switch arr[i] and arr[j]
arr[i]=arr[j]
arr[j]=temp
```

because you can do multiple assignment like this:

```
a,b = 1,2
```

which is the same as:

```
a = 1
b = 2
```

which means you can switch the values of variables like this:

```
a,b = b,a
```

or in your case:

```
arr[i],arr[j] = arr[j],arr[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy implementation of Insertion sort in ruby.

```
def insertion(arr)
  for i in (1...(arr.size))
    if arr[i-1] > arr[i]
      i.downto(1) do |el|
        if arr[el] < arr[el-1]
          arr[el-1], arr[el] = arr[el], arr[el-1]
        end
      end
    end
  end
  arr
end

arr = %w(3 7 4 9 5 2 6 1 0)

p insertion(arr)
```